# How can I make a window like the Mac OS X dock's stack?

Tags: cocoa, macos, dock, windowing

I'm looking to create a window object that looks just like the Dock's Stack. (The grey square one, not the leaning list of pisa).  Complete with title, transparency, navigation buttons, large icons with subtitles, and pointy-arrow bit on the bottom.

The NSPanel "HUD" didn't really fit...  I'd like the thing to pop-up when a user clicks in my app, with the icons indicating actions and the arrow-bit pointing to where they clicked.

help?

Thanks,

-S!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good starting place for the popup window is [MAAttachedWindow](http://mattgemmell.com/2007/10/03/maattachedwindow-nswindow-subclass).

As for the files, labels, etc. you might look into NSCollectionView. I think you can configure it to be transparent, and set the desired label attributes in your NSCollectionViewItem prototype. In this prototype, you might accomplish it with a basic no-border NSImageView and a properly-colored NSTextField.

Comment: Matt Gemmell is awesome.  I'll dl this and see if it works.  I'll accept if it does.

Comment: Yes, he's just the bee's knees ... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use BGHUD for your UI. See:
http://www.binarymethod.com/bghudappkit/

Comment: Very nice. I know there have been several projects to provide "HUD" style AppKit control replacement, but this one is nice.